# catkin-cmake-isolated fails to build moveit_core

Tags: ros, moveit, compilation, debian, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to compile `moveit_core` with `catkin_make_isolated` but it failed because it could find a config file for fcl.

```
-- catkin 0.5.74
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "fcl" with any of
  the following names:

    fclConfig.cmake
    fcl-config.cmake
```

I already installed fcl because `fcl.pc` is present in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`.
Is there a way to use it instead of the cmake config file ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92351/catkin-cmake-isolated-fails-to-build-moveit_core/) by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure that fcl has installed one of the two .cmake files into the location and that it's on the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH correctly if you want to use a non standard location.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2013-10-20**:
Finally, I added a cmake file base on `FindPkgConfig.cmake` to make it work.

**Comment by [silentwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/19240/silentwf/) on 2014-10-29**:
@Fabien R Could you post your cmake file and where you placed it? I'm also facing the same problem as you are.

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2015-01-22**:
It seems that I copied the file to /opt/ros/groovy/share/fcl/cmake and renamed it as fcl-config.cmake.
But a cleaner way is to build fcl source as a package (with check_install for instance) and to use: find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(FCL fcl)
include_directories( ${FCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})